# Why can't one update their own profile during a suspension period?

Tags: discussion, support, network-profile, account-suspension

If a user is suspended temporarily then why can't they update their profile information, like bio and all? Is it included in suspension rules?

Because when I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) I didn't get anything relevant to profile edit or changing settings.

Comment: Probably to eliminate the risk of the user changing their profile into a rant about the unfairness of the suspension.

Comment: Then don't let user change their critical information but I think letting user change his bio should not be a big issue.

Comment: @Chirag but that's where they *could* write a rant. By the time a user has been suspended they have not exactly demonstrated a willingness or ability to act appropriately. Given that they can't take any other action, why should they be able to edit their bio?

Comment: @jonrsharpe then why suspension of editing bio rights is not included in Jeff's post.?

Comment: @Chirag Maybe they didn't have user pages in 2009. Or the system is implemented so that it simply prevents all activity on a specific SE site. In that case, they would have to explicitly program an exception to let a suspended user edit their bio. And there's not much reason to accomodate a suspended user.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes people get a little upset when they get suspended.

I've seen angry mod message replies. Imagine if someone decides he doesn't want his account any more and fills his profile with vulgarities or shock pictures.

It feels like common sense since the point of the suspension is to give the user time to cool down.

It's worth remembering while the blog posts are canonical - they need not be complete. They're primarily informational.

Comment: Currently my account is suspended and I'm not at all in angry mood for moderators. I am angry but for those because of whom I've been suspended. Today I've tried to update my profile with "This person is awesome and I like him." Which opens self profile of user who is visiting my profile. But I was not knowing that this kind of things are also happening on SO. Such users needs to accept there guilt and for them it's time to get matured.

Comment: @Chirag - You do realize that what you wanted to do, most would consider that action, to be passive aggressive behavior.